# Jitsi "cannot connect to the conference" after authentication has been enabled

Tags: jitsi, jitsi-meet

I installed my own Jitsi instance on Ubuntu, following the docs using the official packages. That worked like a charm. But I don't want to have a completely open instance, so I followed https://github.com/jitsi/jicofo#secure-domain to require a login to create a conference.

As far as I can tell, I followed exactly the docs, but after restarting Jitsi I cannot create a conference anymore. I see the following behavior:

- Private URL: I get a message, that the conference has not been started and a "I am the host" button. If I push the button, I'm asked for the credentials. Doing so I get the following error message: "Oops! Something went wrong and we couldn't connect to the conference: connection.GET_SESSION_ID_ERROR"
- Public URL: Browser asks for permission to use mic and camera. Then I see the Jitsi UI but camera and mic disabled. Looks like a "waiting mode".

The original installation docs mentions some log files for debugging. I checked them, but did not found anything that would be helpful or suspicious to me.

Update: If I enter wrong credentials, I get a message that they are wrong. So obviously the checking of the credentials is working.

Any idea how to solve / debug this would be appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found the error at last. My domain is like "jitsi.domain.com". I created a user:

```
test@domain.com
```

and I got an error message that the host is not activated. Only after several trials I realised that the user has to be named

```
test@jitsi.domain.com
```